# Recursion in C: why does my simple code doesn't work?

Tags: c

Given `i` the value of 3, the output should be the sum of `3/(3+1) + 2/(2+1) + 1/(1+1)`, always stopping on 1.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with what I did, thank you for your attention.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int sum_recur(int i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        return sum_recur(i - 1) / (sum_recur(i - 1) + 1);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    printf("Inform a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%d \n", sum_recur(i));
}
```

Comment: Why is it twice `sum_recur(i-1)`? It will always be 1.

Comment: `return sum_recur(i-1)/sum_recur(i-1)+1;` this will always return 2.

Comment: Also note that you're using `int`s, not `float`s or `double`s, so your division will be truncated.

Comment: You so don't add up the values at any point.

Comment: `3/(3+1) + 2/(2+1) + 1/(1+1)` The recursion for that would be `f(n) = n/(n+1) + f(n-1)` but that's nowhere near what the code does.

Comment: yes, I forgot to put parentheses in the example, and in my code too on the line of the first return. About the truncated result, I'm aware. I put the `sum_recur(i-1)` twice because I used it's value twice. in the expression. I put the parentheses I forgot in my code but it still doesn't output the expected value

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be the right recursive implementation of your formula

```
int sum_recur(int i){
    if(i >= 1){
        return (i / (i + 1)) + sum_recur(i-1);
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Also, as @atirit mentioned, you should consider making the output to be `float` or `double` in order to preserve the floating points values of the division result. Otherwise, the result of `sum_recur` will always be 0 since `i / (i + 1)` is always 0 for integer type

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float sum_recur(int i){
    if(i >= 1){
        return (i / (i + 1.0)) + sum_recur(i-1);
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    printf("Inform a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%f \n",sum_recur(i));
}
```

Comment: Ohh! I think I understand now where my rationale was wrong, I wasn't joining the value return by the recursion to something else so it was getting lost. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I believe you're trying to implement, no need for recursion, but it's there if you need it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double sum_recur(double i) {
    if (i < 1) return 0;
    return i / (i + 1) + sum_recur(i - 1);
}

double sum_iter(double i) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (; i >= 1; i--) {
        sum += i / (i + 1);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    printf("Inform a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%f \n", sum_iter((double) i));
    printf("%f \n", sum_recur((double) i));
}
```

The summary is this:

- There's no need for the `math` library.
- Use `float` or `double` and not `int` - in the code itself and in the `printf`.
- Correct the logic in the recursion.
- It can be solved iteratively quite nicely.

Comment: It's work for my school, I need to use recursion :/

Comment: added recursion option

Comment: uhh your code looks nice, but when I tried compiling it it gave it a segmentation fault

Comment: There is a logic error though...```sum_recur``` will return ```1```  when ```i``` gets to ```1```,  But for 1, ```i/(i+1)``` is ```0.5```, no?

Comment: This is the logic as described by his code, I agree with you and this is the way I first implemented it.

Comment: Changed it now back again.

Comment: Was good practice for me to go though that, thanks @UriyaHarpeness

Comment: Different result for `n < 1`

Comment: OK but insufficient: you still do not return `0`. Just simplify the loop: `for (; i >= 1; i--) `

Comment: Correct, it wasn't like this because if the changes I made aling the way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying to achieve from this code. The code that you've written will always return 2.

`sum_recur` will always stop at 1 and you return statement will calculate 1/1+1, which is always 2. For input 3, the `sum_recur` will generate following:

`sum_recur` reaches 1 and hence returns 1 for input value 2

1/1 + 1 = 2, so for i=2 `sum_recur` will again return 2

This is will go on for any input number. This is why no matter what the input is, output of this recursion will always be 2. Further, what you expect this function to do in your question statement is not possible if you're using division between recursion calls. The result that you're looking to achieve is simply addition of 2 n-times or multiplication of 2 with n.

Answer (score 0):

The answers written here explain the problem reasonably well, I just want to add a little bit on your code specifically,
While you do f(i-1)/f(i-1)+1 this is a terrible way of doing this and in case of a larger seed input this might cause you runtime problem with stackoverflow. So I suggest you should try something that's more efficient if at all you have to use recusion. Like this by storing the fun call value

int n = f(i-1);
return n/n +1;